# Как создать цикл в селениуме?

Tags: selenium, node.js

В общем, нужен аналог цикла for. На данный момент код выглядит так:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('.ckeditor_links')).click();
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('#switch_edit-field-body-und-0-value')).click();
}
```

Код, который в цикле, не исполняется вовсе.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сначала объявить ваши элементы:

```
 var webElement1 = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('.ckeditor_links')).click();
 var webElement2 = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('#switch_edit-field-body-und-0-value')).click();
```

Затем для проверки можно в цикле перед каждым действием вставлять:

```
console.log("click element");
```

далее запускаем сам цикл и смотрим консоль

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log("click element "+i);//здесь вывод в консоль вашего счетчика, чтоб видеть каждую итерацию цикла 
    webElement1.click();
    timeout(1000);
    console.log("click element");
    webElement2.click();
}
```

И далее смотреть по выводу в консоли работает ли ваш цикл вообще. По имеющейся информации это пока все, что можно посоветовать. Если не поможет, дайте больше информации по классу и методу где используется данный цикл.

Comment: Эм.. Мне кажется, или язык не совпал?

Comment: Метка node.js - это джаваскрипт. Код в вопросе тоже на джаваскрипте. С каких пор джава умеет `for(var i=0;` вместо `for(int i=0;`?

Comment: Но вообще, идея что-то вывести на консоль хорошая.

Comment: кстати верно,  с `var` я не досмотрел) сейчас погуглю исправлю ответ)